# How to make a copy of /proc/xxxxx?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash, process

A users account have been hacked on one of my servers, where the hacker have started some spam binaries. Before I kill the processes would I like to make a copy of them, but when I

```
tar czf 30333.tar.gz /proc/30333
```

all files are empty.

**Question**

How do I make a copy of `/proc/30333`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one script that allows you to cap the size of files to be saved (here 32 or 64 MiB depending on the shell ) :

```
PID=30333
ulimit -f 65536
cd /proc/$PID || exit 1
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/proc/$PID/$1' sh {} \;
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'cat $1 > /tmp/proc/'$PID'/$1' sh {} \;
tar czf /tmp/$PID.tgz /tmp/proc/$PID
rm -rf /tmp/proc/$PID
```

Answer (score 1):

`/proc` is a virtual file system and doesn't have any **actual** files, but rather contains information on the processes running on the system.

Comment: I can read the files, so there must be a way to copy them.

Comment: If `/proc` contains information, and Jasmine is looking for a way to copy that information. If I can `cat` files in `/proc` then there must be a way to save that information elsewhere, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
cp -r /proc/30333 /root
tar czf /root/30333.tar.gz /root/30333
```

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with this?

Comment: Given that the server has been hacked, "forensically analyze a hostile binary" would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `/proc/30333/exe` is included in what you copy. Not just the symlink, but the actual executable that it is pointing to.

A memory image might be useful too. You can create a core dump by typing:

```
gdb
attach 30333
gcore
```